# Socket Locking across Threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sockets, parallel-processing

Is it a good idea in my ReceiveCallBack of an asynchronous socket to Lock() the socket there?  I'm asking because it's possible that another thread is sending data on the socket at the same time.

```
private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
Socket client = state.workSocket;

lock(client)
{
    int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
    // do some work

    // Kick off socket to receive async again.
    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
}
}    

// This is commonly called by another thread
public void SendMessage(string cmdName, Object data)
{
    lock (client)
    {
         client.Send(arrayofdata, 0, arraylength, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is based on the illusion that you can lock objects to make code thread-safe.  You can't, you can only block code, preventing it from using a shared object at the same time.  The lock statement merely uses an object to store the state.  That should *never* be a socket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to make it thread-safe and be able to send and receive simultaneously you need to create two lock sync objects:

```
private readonly object sendSyncRoot = new object();
private readonly object receiveSyncRoot = new object();

private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket client = state.workSocket;

    lock (receiveSyncRoot)
    {
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
        // do some work

        // Kick off socket to receive async again.
        client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
    }
}

// This is commonly called by another thread
public void SendMessage(string cmdName, Object data)
{
    lock (sendSyncRoot)
        client.Send(arrayofdata, 0, arraylength, 0);
}
```

It is generally a good practice to have dedicated `syncRoot` objects instead of locking on other classes or members. This allows to avoid subtle deadlocks.

Comment: Definitely better to lock some object other than the socket itself.

Comment: Well, I've never locked any sockets in any language when reading from one thread and writing from another. It works just fine in C++, Delphi.  Why is C# different, apart from being managed?  Why does .NET force explicit locking on operations that don't require explicit locks in unmanaged code?  If two threads can write, then fine, do some locking, but one write and one read?

Comment: @Martin James - It depends. If you want reading and writing to happen concurrently, you don't need to lock at all. But if you want two readings or two writings happen simultaneously, you need to lock. I don't know if the provided code is just a sample or real one, but if real one was writing data in more then one send you need to guarantee that no other thread interfere.

Comment: @Martin James - suppose the SendMessage method sends files. So SendMessage inside would read from the file stream and send over the socket. Now suppose two threads started sending. Without locking the content of both files will be mixed together.

Comment: Yes - if there can be more than one writer, you need to do some locking, somewhere.  More than one reader does not seem to make much sense - can't imagine a reason for anyone to attempt it!

Comment: Why do this get upvoted? First of all: Locking the `BeginReceive` doesnt to anything. Several `BeginReceives` can be invoked at any time. As for the sending, it's far better to enqueue everything that should be sent and keep working that queue internally.

Comment: The lock is not just on BeginReceives, there is also 'some work'. I agree it does not make sense if 'ReceiveCallback' is called only recurrently, but it is not clear from the sample code. Also, I agree that maintaining queue is a better option for the sending, but not the only option, right?

Comment: Your code still do not help which the receive problems. The lock is not doing anything to protect the socket. All it do is unnecessary blocking.

Answer (score 4):

No. Do not do that. The best way to handle a socket is encapsulation. Do not expose it to anything but the class declaring it. By doing so it's easy to make sure that only one receive is pending at a time. No need to use a lock for it.

As for the sending. do something like this:

```
public class MyClient
{
    private readonly Queue<byte[]> _sendBuffers = new Queue<byte[]>();
    private bool _sending;
    private Socket _socket;

    public void Send(string cmdName, object data)
    {
        lock (_sendBuffers)
        {
            _sendBuffers.Enqueue(serializedCommand);
            if (_sending) 
                return;

            _sending = true;
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(SendFirstBuffer);
        }
    }

    private void SendFirstBuffer(object state)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] buffer;
            lock (_sendBuffers)
            {
                if (_sendBuffers.Count == 0)
                {
                    _sending = false;
                    return;
                }

                buffer = _sendBuffers.Dequeue();
            }

            _socket.Send(buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

This approach do not block any of the callers and all send requests are processed in turn.